# JQuery with REST and Mongodb

Tags: java, jquery, mongodb

How can updating or deleting a person from MongoDB using `REST` and `Java` be done simply.

I managed to get the searching of an existing person but not adding a new one I almost tried everything that I can find.

Here how the search process is done easily with two classes and jQuery.
I wish to get away to do adding to deleting simply like that.

My jQuery:

```
function searchID()
    {
        var id = document.getElementById("search").value;
        $("#persons").html("");


        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/persons/" + id,  function(data)
        {
            for (var i in data) {
                $('#persons').append("<p>ID: " + data[i].id + "</p>")
                $('#persons').append("<p>First name: " + data[i].firstName + "</p>")
                $('#persons').append("<p>Last name: " + data[i].lastName + "</p><br>")
            }
        }); 

    }
```

From My personDAO class

```
public ArrayList<Person> get(int id)
    {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mongodb");

        MongoCollection<Document> col = database.getCollection("person");     

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("id", new BasicDBObject("$eq", id));

        MongoCursor<Document> cur = col.find(query).iterator();

        while(cur.hasNext())
        {
            Document doc = cur.next();
            List list = new ArrayList(doc.values());

            persons.add(new Person((int) Float.parseFloat(list.get(1).toString()), list.get(2).toString(), list.get(3).toString()));   
        }

        mongoClient.close();

        return persons;
    }
```

From my RestController class

```
@CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/persons/{id}")
    public ArrayList<Person> getPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id)
    {
        personDAO = new PersonDAO();
        return personDAO.get(id);
    }
```

Comment: you want to insert a new document for a new user in database??

Comment: Exactly or deleting document using an id but the two java class and jQuery has to done together that it works.

Comment: A link of my source code https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9H2qsKiTIenNWQtOEdVNlNOYVU

Answer (score 0):

Just like you are sending id of person you want to search from JQuery to Java class you can send data of new person you want to add in collection from Jquery to java. Now once the details are in java class use following command for adding new person

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb");

        MongoCollection<Document> col = database.getCollection("customer");
         Document post = new Document()
            .append("name","sid")
            .append("age","123")
            .append("mobile no", "1234578")
            .append("registration date",new Date());
            col.insertOne(post);
```

For deleting person use following command

```
    Bson filter = new Document("name", condition);
    col.deleteOne(filter);
```